# Handling mouseenter only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’ve created a custom cursor effect. I would like to use it after `mouseenter` event in a specific `<div>` and its children. It works but it’s showing and hiding after every move even if I don’t leave the `<div>`. I’m expecting only one start after hover and stop after `mouseleave`.

The code is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rowek")
    .mouseenter(function(event) {
      $("#follower").show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $("#follower").hide();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {
    var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

    follower = document.getElementById('follower');

    printout = document.getElementById('printout');

    mouseX = (event) => {
      return event.pageX;
    };

    mouseY = (event) => {
      return event.pageY;
    };



    positionElement = (event) => {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
    };

    timer = false;

    window.onmousemove = init = (event) => {
      var _event;
      _event = event;
      return timer = setTimeout(() => {
        return positionElement(_event);
      }, 1);
    };

  }).call(this);
});
```

```css
.rowek-bgr {
  background-color: #313343;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto!important;
}

.child-txt {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.child-special-txt {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

#follower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
}

#follower #circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}

#follower #circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 4s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 4s infinite;
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="rowek">
  <div class="col-md-12 rowek-bgr">
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for adults</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for childrens</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for students</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for grands</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle1"></div>
  <div id="circle2"></div>
</div>
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsLy8hyy/).

Comment: If I had to make a guess? It's the custom pointer. You're moving that under the mouse when you move the mouse, which means that, programmatically, you've moved OUT of the element you'd just mouseentered. I disabled the custom cursor bit, and the mouseenter works just as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/jsLy8hyy/5/

Comment: Should standardize your coding approach and use either jQuery *or' native methods....not both. Mixing them all up makes code base confusing and inconsistent

Comment: I mean that my version is valid for appearance of pointer but the problem is that cursor effect is restarting on every move in rowek DIV. It should start just once and disable only after mouseleave from rowek DIV. Pointer should follow my cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `div` you're using for the effect; it gets under the mouse and catches events before the element behind it, then when you move it triggers the event again because the mouse is once again over the background element.

One way to solve it would be adding `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS for the `#follower` element.

Also, not part of the problem, but since you are using jQuery you should use it for all the event handling instead of mixing in plain JavaScript events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rowek")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $("#follower").show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $("#follower").hide();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

    follower = document.getElementById('follower');

    printout = document.getElementById('printout');

    mouseX = (event) => {
      return event.pageX;
    };

    mouseY = (event) => {
      return event.pageY;
    };



    positionElement = (event) => {
      var mouse;
      mouse = {
        x: mouseX(event),
        y: mouseY(event)
      };
      follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
    };

    timer = false;

  $(window).mousemove(function(_event){
      return timer = setTimeout(() => {
        return positionElement(_event);
      }, 1);    
  })  
});
```

```css
.rowek-bgr {
  background-color: #313343;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto!important;
}

.child-txt {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.child-special-txt {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

#follower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#follower #circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}

#follower #circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 4s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: pulse 4s infinite;
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="rowek">
  <div class="col-md-12 rowek-bgr">
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for adults</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for childrens</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for students</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for grands</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle1"></div>
  <div id="circle2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. Thank you very much. Very interesting case. I've learned the new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

first you dont need to use timeout on #follower
you can get the position of each child when the mouse is hover it
so i remove a part of your code

seconde, with you method, when the mouse hover the child, the #folower went to show but is just under the mouse so the script will call mouseleve on folower child, so the folwer will hide juste after
this is a fast recursive action

```js
`$(document).ready(function() {
    var follower = $('#follower');

    $("#rowek .child").each(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(event) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            $("#follower").show().css({top : offset.top+$(this).height()+50, left : offset.left+(($(this).width()/2)+10)});
            event.preventDefault();
        }, function(event) {
            $("#follower").hide();
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    });

});`
```

```css
   .rowek-bgr {
    background-color: #313343;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child {
    padding: 15px;
    width: auto!important;
}

.child-txt {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

.child-special-txt {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

#follower {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
}

#follower #circle1 {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 0.5s infinite;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: pulse 0.5s infinite;
    background: #ffb83f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0em;
    width: 0em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

#follower #circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 0.7s infinite;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: pulse 0.8s infinite;
    background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0em;
    width: 0em;
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        margin-left: -0.5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="rowek">
  <div class="col-md-12 rowek-bgr">
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for adults</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for childrens</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for students</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 child">
      <span class="child-txt">Test</span> <span class="child-special-txt">for grands</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle1"></div>
  <div id="circle2"></div>
</div>
```